# Export iCloud contacts to Office 365 including profile pictures

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, contacts, icloud

I want to export my contacts from iCloud to Office 365. While I can do this basically using drag & drop with the Apple Contacts app on macOS, it won't preserve the contact picture.

How do I migrate my contacts including as much as possible, but especially the profile picture from iCloud to O365?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research about your issue. As I know, we usually export iCloud contacts to Outlook via .csv, but it seems that profile pictures cannot be imported together. Have not found a solution about that, maybe you can try to refer to the method in [this link](https://www.slipstick.com/exchange/cmdlets/import-images-active-directory/#tools) and see if it could helps.